# Depth First Search Using Adjacency Matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search

Can anyone explain the algorithm for depth first search using Adjacency matrix?
I know the algo of depth first search using recursion and I tried to implement it using Adjacency matrix but it was not very successful.

What I have so far is

```
 dfs(G,i){

  mark i as visited;

  for(traverse through the edges of i vertex){

     if(vertex of edge is unseen){

       DFS(G,newVerted)
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: What's going wrong?  Your pseudo code looks fine in theory (other than the BFS part :).  If you can do DFS with a adjacency list, doing it with a matrix should be just a matter of looping through the row of that matrix and seeing where the bit is set and the vertex hasn't been visited

Comment: Do you understand what Depth First Search is?  Do you understand what an adjacency matrix is?

Answer (score 7):

```
    void DFS(int i)
    {
        int j;
        printf("\n%d",i);
        visited[i]=1;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(!visited[j]&&G[i][j]==1)
                DFS(j);
    }
```

Where `n` is the no of vertices and `G` is the graph and `G[i][j]` indicates vertex `i` is connected to vertex `j`

Answer (score 4):

You missed to print in function `dfs(G,i)`

The code is as follows

```
dfs(G,i){
int j;
printf("%d ",i);
visited[i]=1;
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    if(visited[j]==0&&G[i][j]==1)
        dfs(G,j);
}
```

Here we use variable n as number of vertices in Graph.G is cost adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simplest that just like in labyrinth you always go left. If you come from n node go on next node in cycle in increasing order.

I just do not know how do you know that you came around :D But cool thing is that you do not need extra space and marking.

**EDIT**
example

```
    5
   / \
  7   3
 /\   /\
4  1 6  2
```

Am is then

```
......1
..1....
.1..11.
1.....1
..1...1
..1....
1..11..
```

So ordering start from 5 is
3 6 3 2 3 5 7 1 7 4 7 5 3# and because you went from 5->3

As I said if you are on node you go on next node based on node you came from. Next node you are going to visit is next number from prevous node (not current node you go from).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it by maintaining a stack and a visited-list, and using a while-loop:
Visited is a bool[], initialized to hold false at all positions, and I assume that the call G[node,neighbour] somehow returns a boolean, telling if there is an edge from node to neighbour. (Implicit comparison to 1 or simply make the adjacency matrix hold booleans)
Stack holds the indices of your nodes:

```
dfs(G,i){
    Initialize Stack
    Current = i
    PossibleEdge = 0
    Visited[Current] = true  //You have visited the starting node
    Do {
        While (PossibleEdge < count) {
            if (G[Current,PossibleEdge] && NOT Visited[PossibleEdge]){
                Stack.Push(Current)      //Save state
                Current = PossibleEdge   //Continue with the child node
                Visited[Current] = true 
                PossibleEdge = -1        //So that it will be incremented to 0
            }
            PossibleEdge++
        }
        PossibleEdge = Current           //Continue to next row of "parent node"
        Current = Stack.Pop()            //Get parent node back
    } While (Stack contains nodes)
}
```

I'm sure it could be optimized (and seeing that I'm dead tired, there might be some logical errors), but if the basic procedure makes sense, it's a start!
**EDIT:** Clarifying, and adding this tip: Recursion is probably easier ;)